# Viem wallet client method does not exist / is not available

Tags: metamask, wallets, javascript, frontend

I am trying to interact with a smart contract from a front-end web app using [viem](https://viem.sh/docs/getting-started.html).

I am successfully creating a Wallet Client with my wallet address, but when I call some of its methods, I get the following error:

```
MethodNotFoundRpcError: The method does not exist / is not available.
```

Also, the only method that does not throw error, is not returning the expected result.

Here is my code (with each error presented as a comment):

```
import {
  createPublicClient,
  createWalletClient,
  getContract,
  http,
} from 'viem'

import { cronosTestnet } from 'viem/chains'

const account = '0x...' // My wallet's address
const walletClient = createWalletClient({ 
  account,
  chain: cronosTestnet,
  transport: http()
})

try {
  const accounts = await walletClient.getAddresses()
  console.log(accounts)
  // []
  // Expected an array with the address I passed to walletClient, instead of an empty array
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}

try {
  const accounts = await walletClient.requestAddresses()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
  // MethodNotFoundRpcError: The method does not exist / is not available.
  // Request body: {"method":"eth_requestAccounts"}
  // Details: the method eth_requestAccounts does not exist/is not available
  // Version: viem@1.10.8
}

try {
  const permissions = await walletClient.getPermissions()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
  // MethodNotFoundRpcError: The method does not exist / is not available.
  // Request body: {"method":"wallet_getPermissions"}
  // Details: the method wallet_getPermissions does not exist/is not available
  // Version: viem@1.10.8
}
```

I have tried this with a MetaMask wallet and a crypto.com DeFi wallet, with the exact same results in both cases.

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?